# Pythagorean triplets which satisfy Euler's totient function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Let $\varphi(x)$ be the Euler totient function and $a,b$ and $c$ be natural numbers.

**Question 1**: Are there infinitely many non-trivial solutions of
$$
\varphi(a)^2 = \varphi(b)^2  + \varphi(c)^2  
$$

$$
\varphi(a^2) = \varphi(b^2)  + \varphi(c^2) 
$$
A trivial solution is one which is obtained multiplying a smaller solution with a constant natural number.

The first few solutions are

```
(1004, 802, 604)
(1012, 782, 644)
(1050, 840, 630)
(1056, 816, 672)
(1084, 866, 652)
(1100, 850, 700)
(1136, 904, 688)
(1144, 884, 728)
(1188, 918, 756)
(1200, 960, 720)
```

**Question 2**: Is there a triplet with at least one of the three numbers $a,b$ and $c$ odd?

**Related question**: [Pythagorean triples that “survive” Euler's totient function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657457/pythagorean-triples-that-survive-eulers-totient-function)

Comment: Dunno if it's useful, but the second equation can be rewritten as
$a\phi(a)=b\phi(b)+c\phi(c).$

Comment: which is the same as certain rational coefficients on $a^2$,$b^2$ and $c^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Question 1, here is an infinite family of solutions for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. None these can be obtained by scaling another, so each of them can be reduced to a 'non-trivial' solution, as you call it.

\begin{align}
a &= (n^2+1)^2(n^2-1)(2n) \\
b &= (n^2+1)(n^2-1)^2(2n) \\
c &= (n^2+1)(n^2-1)(2n)^2.
\end{align}

This family was generated by making a family of scaling-different triples using the general formula for Pythagorean triples (which is $a = t(p^2+q^2)$, $b = t(p^2-q^2)$, and $c = t(2pq)$), and then scaling them up to ensure that $a$, $b$, and $c$ have the same prime factors, since then

\begin{equation} \frac{\varphi(a)}{a} = \frac{\varphi(b)}{b} = \frac{\varphi(c)}{c} = \frac{\varphi(a^2)}{a^2} = \frac{\varphi(b^2)}{b^2} = \frac{\varphi(c^2)}{c^2}. \end{equation}