# What's the greatest common divisor of $\phi(n)$ and $n$, where $\phi(n)$ is the Euler Totient Function?

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, totient-function

Question: Is there any formula for finding the $\operatorname{gcd}(\phi(n), n)$?

I'm not sure if this is a dumb question, but I couldn't find one myself and not on Wikipedia.

**EDIT**: To clarify what I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to solve another problem, where I have to plug the greatest common divisor into the Totient function again, and it would be fun if there was an expression for that so it maybe would simplify.

Comment: OEIS sequence [A009195](https://oeis.org/A009195).

Comment: @RobertIsrael Pardon me, I'm quite new to OEIS, the formula section leads to other sequences, does this mean the problem has only been partially solved or?

Comment: Depends on what you really want to do. What is wrong with just $\text{gcd}(\phi(n),n)$?

Comment: @Somos I'm trying to solve another problem, where I have to plug the greatest common divisor into the Totient function again, and it would be fun if there was an expression for that so it maybe would simplify.

Comment: If there were a simpler expression the OEIS would probably have it. This is as simple as it gets unless I am very mistaken. Please edit your question to include your comment in the body of it.

Comment: @Somos Alright, thank you

Comment: @CasimirRönnlöf The edit is still not specific enough. Why don't you just post the concrete problem for which you need the value of this expression ? It is well possible that in the situation in your specific problem , $\ \gcd(\varphi(n),n)\  $ can be calculated as an expression by hand. A general simpler formula won't exist because if we have more than one prime factor, the gcd depends on the existence of a larger prime factor $q$ congruent $1$ to a smaller prime factor $p$ since in this case we get an extra prime factor $p$ in the factorization of $\varphi(n)$

Comment: @Peter Sorry I was in a hurry yesterday and on phone. Coincidentally, I'm trying to give [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657457/pythagorean-triples-that-survive-eulers-totient-function) problem a try, which you have also worked on. Basically I'm just "doodling" around, trying to simplify the 3rd equation given in the problem and the term $\phi(n\phi(n))$ appeared, and since $n$ and $\phi(n)$ are not necessarily relatively prime, I used the formula $$\phi(nm)=\phi(n)\phi(m)\frac{d}{\phi(d)}$$ where $d$ is $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no known closed expression about what you're asking.

However we can do a little bit better than that if we know the factorization of the integer $ n \ = \ p_1^{k_1}...p_r^{k_r}$

$\phi(n) \ = \ p_1^{k_1}...p_r^{k_r}(\frac{p_1 - 1}{p_1})...(\frac{p_r - 1}{p_r}) \ = \ p_1^{k_1-1}...p_1^{k_r-1}(p_1-1)...(p_r-1)$

$\gcd(\phi(n), n)\ =\ \gcd (p_1^{k_1-1}...p_1^{k_r-1}(p_1-1)...(p_r-1),\  p_1^{k_1}...p_r^{k_r})\ =\\ p_1^{k_1-1}...p_1^{k_r-1}\gcd((p_1-1)...(p_r-1), p_1...p_r)$